# What does diff.mnemonicprefix do?

Tags: git

I've noticed that SourceTree performs git commands with this configuration option:

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false
```

This is what the [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/diff-config#Documentation/diff-config.txt-diffmnemonicPrefix) say about this option:

> ### diff.mnemonicprefix

If set, *git diff* uses a prefix pair that is different from the standard "a/" and "b/" depending on what is being compared. When this configuration is in effect, reverse diff output also swaps the order of the prefixes:

> `git diff` compares the (i)ndex and the (w)ork tree;
>
> `git diff HEAD` compares a (c)ommit and the (w)ork tree;
>
> `git diff --cached` compares a (c)ommit and the (i)ndex;
>
> `git diff HEAD:file1 file2` compares an (o)bject and a (w)ork tree entity;
>
> `git diff --no-index a b` compares two non-git things (1) and (2).

I still don't understand what this means. Can someone explain?

Comment: well, it uses different prefixes depending on diffing context.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

`git diff` shows some metadata about the files it is comparing. Ordinarily you might see something like this:

```
diff --git a/foo/bar.txt b/foo/bar.txt        <--
index abcd123..1234abc 100644
--- a/foo/bar.txt                             <--
+++ b/foo/bar.txt                             <--
```

Note how the files are differentiated using `a/` and `b/` on the three lines I have indicated with arrows. This is non-mnemonic; the characters `a` and `b` have no real significance.

With `diff.mnemonicprefix` enabled, these characters are chosen as described in the documentation you quoted. For example, if you have changes to your local copy and are comparing against the index (e.g. with `git diff`) you would see something like

```
diff --git i/foo/bar.txt w/foo/bar.txt
index abcd123..1234abc 100644
--- i/foo/bar.txt
+++ w/foo/bar.txt
```

instead. The characters `i` and `w` are used to indicate your index and working copy respectively.

The other cases listed in the documentation work similarly.